# Background image not appearing in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, background-image

My background image not appearing in WordPress though I have included this code in my **style.css**

```
body{
  background: url("/wp-content/themes/my_theme/images.png");
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you please show the location of the stylesheet. you are using an absolute url so that must be the issue.

Comment: @khalil <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/style.css" />

Comment: Have you tried?
body{
  background: url("images.png");
}

Comment: @khalil no that didn't work.It's a WordPress site.

Comment: Does it work if you use the entire url e.g. `"http://www.yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/my_theme/images.png"`? if not then your path is incorrect.
Also, usually you'd put theme images in their own folder named 'images' or 'assets' etc, not in the root of your theme folder..

Comment: My image is in the root of my theme folder.I am Working on localhost server.

Comment: @MustafizurRahman try adding a style tag in the header.php:
<style>body { background: url('<?php  bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/images.png');
background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style>

Comment: Also what other properties the body element has?

Comment: @khalil brother I have tried your solution but it didn't work also.The body element has only one property which is section and  id name is test.

Comment: how about '/images.png' assuming 'style.css' is also in the root

Comment: @Jasmine no, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

To add the theme background image in wordpress add the below code in css file .Used ../  to go to folder instead of using the full path

```
body{
background: url("../images.png");
}
```

Comment: Please send me the site url and let me know which image is not appearing on background .

Answer (score 0):

`body { background: url("./images.png");}`

I tried this out with a test site local hosted on XAMPP. Single dot for relative URL in the same directory, it must be a Wordpress/localhost thing because usually just `"images.png"` works.

Answer (score 0):

okay I find it out.
My wp-content folder was also inside a folder named wordpress.
so the correct code would be :

body {

background : url("/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my_theme/images.png");

}